# like command in sql query

Tags: sql

I have a column that contains the value: "Mandatory info on model l_90 with features games_14. Please provide the info for this model.[server=stack3_112] "

i want to run only the first part, "Mandatory info on model l_90 with features games_14" and exclude "Please provide info for this model" from the result.

I tried

```
model like '% Mandatory info on model l_90 with features games_14%'
```

in the select but it didn't give me what I wanted.

Comment: Tag the dbms product you use, you've already got product specific answers...

Comment: Should "Please provide info for this model" removed from all rows? (No matter if model l_90 is mentioned.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to have only part of this column returned in your query.  See:

```
select substr(your_column, 1, INSTR(your_column, 'Please'))
  from table
where your_column like '%Mandatory info on model l_90 with features games_14%'
```

This will give you a substring of everything up until the first point it finds "Please".

Note: I'm not sure what dbms you are on but the above select will work in Oracle.

Comment: Hi Daniel thank you it works fine now iam able to get the expected results

Comment: Great!  Please mark this as the answer to your question so others will see this as the answer if they also have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE {column name} like '% Mandatory info on model I_90 with features games_14%
AND {column name} NOT LIKE '%Please%')
```

Could this work?

This way any text that contains 'please' should be filtered out

Comment: Thanks drzounds for your answer i tried but giving zero records

Comment: drzounds your answer helps me to work on this . i appreciate your assistance thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'Mandatory info on model l_90 with features games_14'
from table
where column like '%Mandatory info on model l_90 with features games_14%'
```